# how to add a table to an existing db schema created using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate, here my question is

> I created a db schema using the hibernate 10 days back but due to
>   requirement I need to create a new table in that db schema, I tried by
>   adding  to hibernate.cfg.xml with hbm2ddl.auto as update,
>   after that my new table not created and I tried with hbm2ddl.auto as
>   create with other tempdb whole structure is recreated but my db have
>   much data which is essential for me.

### So how to create that new table with out losing the other db schema and if i need to alter the table structure how to done

Comment: As per my understand, you need to create table in schema manually and map in .hbm file from hibernate.

Comment: **hbm2ddl.update** should update the schema (it's a different topic whether it's a good practice or not). Does the DB-user have the required rights? Have you remapped a one-to-many -join to use a join table?

Comment: @Jani is right, if you dont want to create manually another solution is just create a dummy database and let it generate all tables. than use that table script to your Production/main database.

Comment: @jani,@yogesh thanks for your suggestion, if we done in the same way whats the fullfledged use of hibernate. can anyone suggest other